# Is typeid() enough for type safety?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, rtti, type-safety, typeid

I was wondering if `typeid` is a "hard enough" criterion for type safety to forego all the usual precautions. Specifically, consider the following code snippet:

```
class storage
{
private:
    std::map<std::type_index, void*> objects;

public:
    template<typename T>
    void put(T* ptr)
    {
        objects[typeid(*ptr)] = ptr;
    }
};

storage stor;

ClassA* a = new ClassA();
ClassB* b = new ClassB();

stor.put(a);
stor.put(b);
```

Is it safe to get the objects back from the map using the information from `typeid`?

```
template<typename T>
T* storage::get()
{
    return static_cast<T*>(objects[typeid(T)]);
}
```

Thanks,
N.

Comment: Since `ClassA` and `ClassB` can be _implicitly_ converted to `void*` you don't need to use `static_cast` to store them in the map.

Comment: I wanted to make clear what the conversions are, but edited the example accordingly.

Comment: I also edited the example so that pointers are stored under their real type `typeid(*ptr)` to prevent issues with abstract base classes.

Answer (score 1):

It works, in the sense that `a2` has the same value as `a`.

It's not necessarily "safe". For example, if `a` pointed to an instance of some derived class of `A`, then `a2` would not be guaranteed to have the same value as `a`. So safety depends what you mean by "forgo the usual precautions". You can't forgo the "precaution" that if you convert a pointer to `void*` then you need to convert it back to its original type.

Comment: I have edited the question to resemble a bit closer the actual code of interest. In this situation, what I put into the map and what I want to get out should never be different types.